# easylist and \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

Tags: input-encodings, easylist

With the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{easylist}

\begin{document}
\begin{easylist}[enumerate]
  § A first item
      §§ A sub item
      §§ another subitem    
\end{easylist}
\end{document}
```

We get the desired output:

[image]

But if the line `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` is uncommented, we'd then get:

[image]

While this can be fixed by either (a) using XeLaTeX, or (b) `\usepackage[at]{easylist}` and `@` instead of `§`, is there a way to make `§` markers work with `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` in pdfLaTeX?

Comment: Short answer: no. The `easylist` marker must be a single character, but in UTF-8 `§` is two byte long: blind alley.

Comment: thanks @egreg , can you add that as an answer?

Comment: @egreg this can't be the reason: § is two bytes in utf8 regardless if you load inputenc or not. The difference is that its first byte  is active.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That was a “short answer”: try with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and you'll see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following hack that changes the unicode character § to be an `easylist` item inside the `easylist` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{easylist}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A7}{\easylistitemornot}
\let\easylistitemornot\S

\def\easylist{%
  \def\easylistitemornot{\futurelet\elNextToken\elCreateItem}%
  \begingroup\elPredefinedStyle}%
\def\endeasylist{\endgroup\par}
\def\Activate{%
  \def\easylistitemornot{\futurelet\elNextToken\elCreateItem}%
}
\def\Deactivate{%
  \let\easylistitemornot\S
}

\begin{document}
\begin{easylist}[enumerate]
  § A first item
      §§ A sub item
      §§ another subitem    
\end{easylist}

Here we have a real §.
\end{document}
```

Nevertheless I would recommend to use, e.g., option `at` to change the item marker:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[at]{easylist}

\begin{document}
\begin{easylist}[enumerate]
  @ A first item
      @@ A sub item
      @@ another subitem    
\end{easylist}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, works great! agree that using `at` and `@` is much cleaner, but was just wondering if it's possible.