# more than 4 levels of outline with outlines package

Tags: lists, outlines

I use the `outlines` package a lot. Today for the first time I need an outline with 5 or maybe 6 levels. But this turns out not to work.

The [documentation](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/outlines/outlines.pdf) is pretty clear that four levels is indeed the limit --- but I need more in this case, so I'm wondering if there's an easy way to change it.

Since I'm in a hurry I'll be grateful for an answer that just hacks something with the right appearance, but in the longer term I really want a way to add commands like `\5`, `\6`, `\7` that work as an `outlines` user would expect them to.

Here's a minimal not-working example. The error is that `\5` is an undefined control sequence.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{outlines}

% I like each level to just bullet points instead of alternating bullets and dashes
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\bullet$}
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\bullet$}
\renewcommand{\labelitemiii}{$\bullet$}
\renewcommand{\labelitemiv}{$\bullet$}
% there is no \labelitemv command

\begin{document}

\begin{outline}
    \1 hello at level 1
        \2 hello at level 2
            \3 hello at level 3
                \4 hello at level 4
                    \5 oops this is an error
\end{outline}

\end{document}
```

Comment: outlines.sty has only around 100 lines of code. Simply make a copy under another name. Open that and then make some educated guesses how to extend the i,ii,iii,iiii to also support iiiii and iiiiii.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer that's a reasonable suggestion, I will probably try that if there isn't an off the shelf solution

Answer (score 1):

An alternative may be [easylist](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/easylist/easylist-doc.pdf), which does not have a limit of four levels. The list specification works with repeating a character to determine the level. Below I defined an itemize-like list style with a bullet and indentation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[at]{easylist}
\NewList(%
    Hide=1000,Progressive*=1em,Hang=true,%
    Style*=$\bullet$\hskip.6em)

\begin{document}
\begin{easylist}
@ hello at level 1
 @@ hello at level 2
  @@@ hello at level 3
   @@@@ hello at level 4
    @@@@@ not an error anymore
     @@@@@@ level 6
\end{easylist}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

With a bit of trouble (i.e., setting category codes) you can also define `\1`, `\2` etc:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[at]{easylist}
\NewList(%
    Hide=1000,Progressive*=1em,Hang=true,%
    Style*=$\bullet$\hskip.6em)

\xdef\AtCatcode{\number\catcode`@}
\catcode`@=\active
\def\1{@}
\def\2{@@}
\def\3{@@@}
\def\4{@@@@}
\def\5{@@@@@}
\def\6{@@@@@@}
\catcode`@=\AtCatcode

\begin{document}
\begin{easylist}
\1 hello at level 1
 \2 hello at level 2
  \3 hello at level 3
   \4 hello at level 4
    \5 not an error anymore
     \6 level 6
\end{easylist}
\end{document}
```

A limitation of easylist is that you cannot use the list symbol within the list items (outside of the list it works normally), so for example `@@@ item with an @ character` or `\3 item with an @ character` would not work. The package provides some other characters to choose from, like ¶ and §, which are probably never used or easily avoided, but they are difficult to type. However, with the approach of defining `\1`, `\2` etc you can bypass this difficulty and still reduce the chance of triggering the limitation. For example for ¶ (the pilcrow, character code `b6`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pilcrow]{easylist}
\NewList(%
    Hide=1000,Progressive*=1em,Hang=true,%
    Style*=$\bullet$\hskip.6em)

\xdef\PilcrowCatcode{\number\catcode`^^b6}
\catcode`^^b6=\active
\def\1{^^b6}
\def\2{^^b6^^b6}
\def\3{^^b6^^b6^^b6}
\def\4{^^b6^^b6^^b6^^b6}
\def\5{^^b6^^b6^^b6^^b6^^b6}
\def\6{^^b6^^b6^^b6^^b6^^b6^^b6}
\catcode`^^b6=\PilcrowCatcode

\begin{document}
\begin{easylist}
\1 hello at level 1
 \2 hello at level 2
  \3 hello at level 3
   \4 hello at level 4
    \5 not an error anymore
     \6 sixth level
\end{easylist}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hah! As a person with a UK Mac keyboard layout I have an entire key dedicated to the § character and I've never had a reason to use it before. This package looks really useful, thank you for the answer.

Comment: @N.Virgo note that the § character for easylist doesn't work anymore with pdfLaTeX on a modern installation due to changes in the default input encoding (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350330/easylist-and-usepackageutf8inputenc which also provides a fix). XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX still work with the original package though.